# Connecting to Yii2 with socket.io

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, socket.io, yii2

I have a Yii2 view and I want to run a socket.io port on it. The website is on a virtual host under name `http:/yii.loc/`. To run  socket.io on my view I have the following code:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://yii.loc');
var http = require('http').createServer(socket);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected!');
});
```

When I do `node app.js`, it console logs `listening on *:3000` in Git Bash, but I still can't connect when going to `http:/yii.loc/`. I have tried `http://yii.loc:3000/`, but it doesn't load up. How can I run socket.io on my view?

Comment: Have you port-forwarded?

Comment: No, how can I do that?

Comment: Make sure that the firewall allows your external requests to be handled by Yii2.

Comment: I turned the firewall off but the issues are the same

Comment: What's the code you're trying to connect to socket.io with? I don't think you can do it by putting thte url into a web browser.

Comment: I have the `socket.io.js` script added to my view, which is the script from `socket.io-client` module

Comment: Can you show us that code?

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/dist/socket.io.js

Comment: I mean the code in your view

Comment: I have copied the code into my `web` directory and added it to my view like this:
`$this->registerJsFile("/socket.io/socket.io.js");`